# Racket function to find the first element in a list that matches a predicate

Tags: racket

In Linq (.NET), there is a `First()` method that takes a collection and a predicate, and returns the first element in the list that matches. For example, the following...

```
numbers.First(n => n % 2 == 0)
```

...returns the first even number in `numbers`. I want to do the same in Racket.

I came up with the following...

```
(define (first-match f lst)
  (first (filter f lst)))
```

...but I am suspicious that this may be very inefficient, as I think it will filter the **entire** list before applying `first`. The Linq version checks each element as it goes, so will only traverse the list until it finds a matching element.

Can anyone confirm or contradict my assumption that my `first-match` function will traverse the entire list, and if it does, how can I produce a more efficient version of Linq's `First()` method?

I tried the following version of the code...

```
(define (first-match f lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) #f]
        [(f (first lst)) (first lst)]
        [else (first-match f (rest lst))]))
```

...which will only traverse as far as is needed, so should be more efficient, but
based on a few tests, this wasn't much faster, leading me to believe that either the first version isn't traversing the whole list, or the second is.

Anyone able to comment?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct in your assumption that `(filter f lst)` will traverse the whole input list (and create a new list on top of that!) before passing the result to `first`. Your second version is more efficient, and will only traverse the list until the element is found.

But there's an easier solution in Racket, there's a built-in procedure that does *exactly* what you want: behold [`findf`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._findf%29%29)!

```
(findf even? '(1 3 5 2 4))
=> 2
(findf even? '(1 3 5 7 9))
=> #f
```

Comment: That's great, thanks for confirming my suspicions, and thanks again for pointing out the `findf` function.  It seemed likely that there had to be such a function in Racket, but I didn't manage to find it.